# What is the best way to make calls to my own API on a live node server?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

I have made a web application with a simple API. The code for the front-end and and the API are both served from the same host. The front end consumes the API by making basic http requests. While developing, I have been making these requests within the front-end using port 3000 from the locally run server.

What is the best way to do this on a production server (An AWS EC2 instance)?

How do I easily generalize this in the development code so I don't have to change it from

```
axios.get("localhost:3000" + otherParams)
        .then(response => {

          //use the response to do things

          });
        })
```

to

```
axios.get("http://99.999.999.999:80" + otherParams)
        .then(response => {

          //use the response to do things

          });
        })
```

every time I push an update to the live server? Is this just something that web developers have to put up with? Sorry if this is a dumb question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We definitely don't have to put up with changing our code like that every time! (Thank the coding gods)

So I think what you are after is [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

For example: You could setup an environment variable called `SERVER_URL`

Then when you are running locally that variable is  `localhost:3000` but when you deploy to amazon it can be set to `http://99.999.999.999:80`

in node you consume the variable like this

`process.env.WHATEVER_YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME_IS`

So in your case it would be
`axios.get(process.env.SERVER_URL + otherParams)`

a popular module to help create these variables is [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv), which is worth looking at.

As a little bonus answer to help (and hopefully not confuse you too much), axios lets you [create your own instance of axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) so that you don't have to repeat yourself. Their example is

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

So you could do something like

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.SERVER_URL
});
```

then you can replace your `axios` calls with your new instance of axios (`api`)

Something like this.

```
api.get(otherParams)
```

Hope that makes some sense and gets you back on track!

Comment: I believe I am using axios more intelligently now thanks to you. Appreciate it.

Comment: @DanielWhite Awesome! I’m glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a config.js file:

```
var configs = {};
configs.appPort = 3000;
configs.host = '192.168.99.100';
module.exports = configs;
```

Importing the configure file:

```
var configs = require('./config');
```

Axios:

```
axios.get(configs.host + ":" + configs.appPort + "/" + otherParams)
        .then(response => {

          //use the response to do things

          });
        })
```

You can also create environment variables like this:

```
configs.isProduction = false;
configs.localHost = "localhost";
configs.productionHost = "192.168.99.100";
```

And then you can check in your app if it is production, use productionHost, otherwise, use localHost.